# how can open file from memory or buffer in android?

Tags: android, pdf, encryption, bufferedreader

I have Ebook (pdf and epub) file with my encrypted Algorithm. How can I open book and decrypt Ebook files but don`t save in SD Card and Open files from memory buffer with default device readers like adobe reader or ebookdroid and ...  ?
I use eclipse and java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are welcome to create a `ContentProvider` that can serve your content via `openFile()`. [This sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ContentProvider/Pipe) illustrates the basic technique, but you would replace the code that reads my sample file with code to use your decrypted memory buffer. You can then use a `Uri` pointing to your `ContentProvider` to allow it to be read by other apps (my sample app shows opening a PDF file this way).

However:

- You will not have enough memory for a very large book.
- Not all PDF or EPUB viewers will honor `content://` `Uri` values.
- Unless the passphrase is the user's own passphrase, your encryption is generally pointless, as anyone who wants to is welcome to reverse-engineer your app to determine your 
  decryption algorithm and hard-coded passphrase.